Recaptcha v2 always false. Ruby on Rails 7
I tried to add recaptcha on site and i use gem for that. I use recaptcha v3 and if it fails then i add v2 to the form.like that:
$("#captcha-v2-<%= @modal %>").html("<%= j recaptcha_tags(site_key: Rails.application.credentials.recaptcha_v2['site_key']) %>");

However v3 works fine, but v2 always false. Can anyone help me?
my controller looks like that:
  def send_callback_email
    callback = params[:callback]
    @action = params["action"]
    @modal = "callback"
    v3_secret = Rails.application.credentials.recaptcha_v3['secret_key']
    v2_secret = Rails.application.credentials.recaptcha_v2['secret_key']
    @success = verify_recaptcha(action: @action, minimum_score: 0.7, secret_key: v3_secret) ||
               verify_recaptcha(secret_key: v2_secret)
    if @success && callback[:agreement]
      ClientServiceMailer.callback_email(callback[:callback_client_name], callback[:callback_client_phone]).deliver_now
    end
    render "mailer_reply"
  end

i add
grecaptcha.reset()

But i think it`s useless cause js create a new recaptcha every time after fail. So i add it just incase. Also i tried to add v2 without js. I checked keys and tried to do the same as in example. I do not want to use Stimulus and turbo for my site but i add them for test. And i tried to create another pair of keys incase something wrong with mine, and i tried to use google test keys. And anyway recaptcha fails. I have no idea why is that happening.
